# Qt Creator. Qt Quick Application screen doesn't show up on my Android device

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, mainwindow

I'm new to Qt Creator and I'm attempting to create a simple application. So far it's only very basic with just the main screen.
I have written the QML code, and tried to run it on my OnePlus One Android phone.
I have all the necessary components in order to run the program on my phone, as the Qt examples have all worked fine.

The application builds and installs on my device, however It resolves in a blank black screen, with nothing on it. I have tried for about 2 hours different possible solutions, but nothing has worked. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

My QML code (the pictures are correctly added to the directory), everything else is unaltered:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Window {
    id: applicationWindow1
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "#343434"


    Image {
        id: cammbutticon
        x: 208
        y: 169
        width: 150
        height: 150
        opacity: 1
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        source: "camera-icon.png"


        Rectangle {
            id: centRect
            width: 150
            height: 150
            opacity: 1
            color: "#00000000"
            radius: 35
            border.color: "#ef0707"
            border.width: 3

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseAreaCam
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: 'GO TO CAMERA'
            }

        }
    }

    Image {
        id: exitman
        x: 473
        y: 338
        width: 150
        height: 120
        opacity: 1
        sourceSize.height: 250
        sourceSize.width: 250
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: -15
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: -10
        source: "exitman.png"


        Rectangle {
            id: exitRect
            x: 37
            y: 12
            width: 100
            height: 100
            opacity: 1
            color: "#00000000"
            radius: 35
            border.width: 3
            border.color: "#ef0707"
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 20
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 15

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseAreaExit
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: Qt.quit()
            }

        }
    }
    Label {
        id: welcometext
        width: 227
        height: 130
        opacity: 1
        color: "#ef0707"
        text: qsTr("WELCOME TO THE APPLICATION")
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: -8
        styleColor: "#f9f9f9"
        style: Text.Normal
        font.bold: false
        font.pointSize: 20
        font.family: "Arial"
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -123
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 1
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Your main.cpp might also be relevant. Is anything printed on the console? Possibly the QML file isn't found at all, or it bails out with some error.

Comment: Have you tried running on your desktop? It's usually easier to start there rather than on an Android device.  Also, this line looks very suspicious: `onClicked: 'GO TO CAMERA'`